# How do I prevent URL entry and redirect the user to login page?

Tags: asp.net

I am using forms authentication on ASP.NET. If I try to access a page by copying the query string and pasting it into the browser, it allows me access to the page.

How can this be prevented? I want the user to always have to login.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the authentication mode in your web.config

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="Authen" protection="All" timeout="60" loginUrl="login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to it. You could enhance your answer by adding the link to the loginUrl Property

Comment: current it says <allow users="*"/> on the authorization.

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict access to certain pages by using the [`<location>`](http://www.dnzone.com/go?60) element. So for example to restrict access to the sub-folder `admin`:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- enable Forms authentication -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms 
            name="MyAuth" 
            loginUrl="login.aspx" 
            protection="All" 
            path="/" 
        />
    </authentication>
</system.web>

<!-- restrict access to the admin subfolder 
     and allow only authenticated users -->
<location path="admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add something similar in the web.config file:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

That should fix the problem. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815151

Answer (score 0):

Apart from configuring authentication in the *web.config* file, you can also use the Global.asax **Session_Start(...)** method to check for users new session, also be sure you revise the session cookie, if it is null you should redirect the user to the login page:

```
public class Global:System.Web.HttpApplication 
{
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if(Session.IsNewSession) 
        {
            if (Request.Headers["Cookie"] != null) 
            {
                if (Request.Headers["Cookie"].IndexOf("Web_App_Login_Cookie", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    Context.User = null;
                    Response.Redirect("~/logOn.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you store user session information in some class you can override the **OnInit(...)** method in some base class to ensure the user already exists in some custom session collection, if not once again you should redirect to login Page.

```
public class SessionBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)            
        {
            UserSession = HttpContext.Current.GetUserSession();
            if (UserSession != null)
            {
                LoggedUserInfo = HttpContext.Current.GetLoggedUserInfo();
                HttpContext.Current.UpdateLoggedUserInfo();
            }
            else { Response.Redirect("~/logOn.aspx", true); }
        }
    }
}
```